# How to stop valgrind "signal 11 being dropped from thread 0' queue"

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

I have some buggy c program to play with valgrind, but after running it with valgrind I am unable to stop infinite loop. ctrl+x, ctrl+z don't help

Comment: same as ctrl+z and ctrl+x

Comment: It would be best if you provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Does your program have any explicit signal handling in it? The [valgrind docs](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html) say: "Valgrind's signal simulation is not as robust as it could be. Basic POSIX-compliant sigaction and sigprocmask functionality is supplied, but it's conceivable that things could go badly awry if you do weird things with signals."

Comment: If your code is ignoring all trappable signals, then just kill it with `SIGKILL`.

Comment: thank you pointing me out to SIGKILL